# o_datetime creating new column instead of changing existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Wrestling with this for 7 hours now. Needed some help.

Problem: Using Pandas' `to_datetime` function, new column is being created instead of converting existing column

Below my code, it will take the csv file at the same location of the script file.

```
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from os import path
import datetime
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
table_fqfn = script_path + "\\date_chairperson.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(table_fqfn)
#CONVERT DATA TYPES
print (type(df['meeting_date']))
print (df.dtypes)
print (df)
df['new_meeeting_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['meeting_date'])
print (type(df['meeting_date']))
print (df.dtypes)
print (df)
print (df['new_meeting_date'])
```

CSV looks like this

[image]

[image]

If I deliberately ask Python To Craete a New Column with the Converted Date

```
df['new_meeeting_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['meeting_date'])
```

it duly obliges

[image]

however, trying to access it:

print (df['new_meeting_date'])

[image]

Comment: There is typo `eee` - `df['new_meeeting_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['meeting_date'])`

Comment: And if need change existing, why not assign back? `df['meeting_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['meeting_date'])` ?

Comment: AH! There it is! 7 hours! thank you sooo much!!!